# Understanding standard errors in logistic regression

Tags: self-study, logistic, interpretation, stata, standard-error

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of the standard errors in my thesis analysis and whether they indicate that my data (and the estimates) are not good enough.

I am performing an analysis with Stata, on immigrant-native gap in school performance (dependent variable = good / bad results) controlling for a variety of regressors. I used both logit and OLS and I adjusted for cluster at the school level.

The regressors which are giving me trouble are some interaction terms between a dummy for country of origin and a dummy for having foreign friends (I included both base-variables in the model as well). In the logit estimation, more than one of the country*friend variables have a SE greater than 1 (up to 1.80 or so), and some of them are significant as well. This does not happen with the OLS.

I am really confused on how to interpret this. I have always understood that high standard errors are not really a good sign, because it means that your data are too spread out. But still (some of) the coefficients are significant, which works perfect for me because it is the result I was looking for. Can I just ignore the SE? Or does it raise a red flag regarding my results? I usually just ignore the SE in regressions (I know, it is not really what one should do) but I can't recall any other example with such huge SE values.

Comment: How is it that you ran this model as both OLS and as a logistic regression? That doesn't make sense. Also, you state that you are adjusting for clustering in the data; that implies that this is a mixed-effects model, in which case it should be GLiMM or LMM, but you don't say anything about that. Can you clarify what the nature of your analysis is?

Comment: I would bet dollars to donuts that you're interpreting the index function coefficients (from the output of logit) as the marginal effects. Is that why you're worried about the standard error being greater than 1? Learning anything from the interaction coefficients of the index function is very tricky in non-linear models (even with the sign). It's much more intuitive with OLS.

Comment: @gung I initially run the model as a logit in order to obtain the probability of having good school results. As I have a binary outcome I was told logistic regression was a good choice (or at least, that's my understanding of logistic regressions!). Then, my professor wanted me to perform the same model as OLS for the reason pointed out by Dimitriy V. Masterov: it's hard to learn anything on interaction coefficients with a logit. In this way, I could tell a bit more on what I found as estimates. Therefore I ran both regressions.

Comment: However, I wanted to see whether the results in the two model were (kind of) alike, in terms of direction of the effect found, and I saw those huge SE. I am not really good in these stuff, but it looked really odd to me. I am 100% sure i am looking at the SE, not the index function coefficients! @DimitriyV.Masterov

Comment: @gung Concerning the cluster, here again I am not really good in that. However, I wanted to control for the fact that performance of kids in the same school may be correlated (same environment, same teachers perhaps etc.). Therefore I used cluster (school) at the end of the regression command, I thought it was better than simply adding robust. But, as I said already 10 times it's one of my first analysis ever, so there are good chances I am taking meaningless decisions about the model to run.

Comment: @maria Marginal effects also have standard errors, but you need the margins command to get them. The SEs of the index function coefficients are on a different scale, so they are not probabilities.

Answer (score 3):

I think the first thing you need to ensure is that you're not comparing apples to orangutans. Then we will discuss standard errors, statistical significance, and model selection.

Here's how you might compare OLS/LPM and logit coefficients for dummy-dummy interactions. We will model union membership as a function of race and education (both categorical) for US women from the NLS88 survey.

First, we will use OLS with factor variable notation for the interactions:

```
. sysuse nlsw88, clear
(NLSW, 1988 extract)

. reg union i.race##i.collgrad

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =    1878
-------------+------------------------------           F(  5,  1872) =    7.02
       Model |  6.40214176     5  1.28042835           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  341.434386  1872  .182390164           R-squared     =  0.0184
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.0158
       Total |  347.836528  1877  .185315146           Root MSE      =  .42707

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              union |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
               race |
             black  |   .0799445   .0250534     3.19   0.001     .0308089    .1290801
             other  |   .1157454   .1076307     1.08   0.282    -.0953433    .3268342
                    |
           collgrad |
      college grad  |   .0975234   .0261143     3.73   0.000     .0463072    .1487395
                    |
      race#collgrad |
black#college grad  |   .0415079   .0563381     0.74   0.461    -.0689841        .152
other#college grad  |  -.0350234   .1867622    -0.19   0.851    -.4013073    .3312606
                    |
              _cons |   .1967546   .0136007    14.47   0.000     .1700804    .2234288
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For instance, black women who also graduated from college are 4.15 percentage points more likely to be in a union.

Now we fit a logit model:

```
. logit union i.race##i.collgrad, nolog

Logistic regression                               Number of obs   =       1878
                                                  LR chi2(5)      =      33.33
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -1029.9582                       Pseudo R2       =     0.0159

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              union |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
               race |
             black  |   .4458082   .1361797     3.27   0.001      .178901    .7127154
             other  |   .6182459   .5452764     1.13   0.257    -.4504762    1.686968
                    |
           collgrad |
      college grad  |   .5320064   .1397767     3.81   0.000     .2580491    .8059637
                    |
      race#collgrad |
black#college grad  |   .0885629   .2791468     0.32   0.751    -.4585548    .6356807
other#college grad  |  -.2543746    .918575    -0.28   0.782    -2.054748    1.545999
                    |
              _cons |  -1.406703   .0801078   -17.56   0.000    -1.563712   -1.249695
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The logit index function coefficients are not particularly meaningful since they are not effects on the probability of union membership. The sign and the significance might tell you something, but the magnitude of the effect is not clear. Also note that the standard errors are large, like in your own data. For instance, the SE of the college graduate of other race coefficient is almost 1.

To get something comparable to OLS, we will use `margins` with the contrast operator:

```
. margins r.race##r.collgrad

Contrasts of predictive margins

Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(union), predict()

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                     |         df        chi2     P>chi2
-----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------
                                                race |
                                   (black vs white)  |          1       14.34     0.0002
                                   (other vs white)  |          1        1.20     0.2725
                                              Joint  |          2       15.14     0.0005
                                                     |
                                            collgrad |          1       19.09     0.0000
                                                     |
                                       race#collgrad |
(black vs white) (college grad vs not college grad)  |          1        0.44     0.5085
(other vs white) (college grad vs not college grad)  |          1        0.03     0.8666
                                              Joint  |          2        0.48     0.7869
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                     |            Delta-method
                                                     |   Contrast   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------
                                                race |
                                   (black vs white)  |   .0901999   .0238201      .0435134    .1368864
                                   (other vs white)  |   .1070922   .0976013     -.0842029    .2983873
                                                     |
                                            collgrad |
                 (college grad vs not college grad)  |    .108149   .0247526      .0596347    .1566633
                                                     |
                                       race#collgrad |
(black vs white) (college grad vs not college grad)  |    .041508   .0627785     -.0815355    .1645515
(other vs white) (college grad vs not college grad)  |  -.0350233   .2084485     -.4435749    .3735282
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These are pretty close to the OLS effects. For instance, black women who graduated from college are also 4.15 percentage points more likely to be in a union according to the logit model. The SEs are somewhat smaller.

Sometimes you can't run the margins command because you don't have the data. All you have are the logit coefficients from someone's paper. While I said they were not particularly meaningful in their raw form, you can transform the logit index function coefficients into a multiplicative effect by exponentiating them, which is easy enough with a calculator. For example, the index function coefficient for black college graduates was .0885629. If I exponentiate it, I get $\exp(.0885629)=1.092603$. This tells me that black college graduates are 1.09 times more likely to be union members compared to a baseline of $\exp(-1.406703)=0.24494955$ (the baseline is the exponentiated constant from the logit). So this means that the union rate for black college graduates will be $0.24\cdot 1.09$ or about $26$%. OLS and logit with margins, will give the *additive* effect, so there we get about $19.67+4.15=23.87$. That's pretty darn close. It won't always work out so nicely.

Stata will give you exponentiated coefficients when you specify odds ratios option `or`:

```
. logit union i.race##i.collgrad, or nolog
```

or just use `logistic`:

```
. logistic union i.race##i.collgrad, nolog
```

I learned about these tricks from [Maarten L. Buis.](http://maartenbuis.nl/publications/interactions.html) There are lots of examples with interactions of various sorts and nonlinear models at that link.

In my toy example, I did not cluster my errors, but that doesn't change the main thrust of these results. Some people don't like clustered standard errors in logit/probits because if the model's errors are heteroscedastic the parameter estimates are inconsistent.

After that long detour, we finally get to statistical significance. In all the models above (OLS, logit index function, logit margins, and OR logit), all the interactions are statistically insignificant (though the main effects generally are not). The standard errors are large compared to the estimates, so the data is consistent with the effects on all scales being zero (the confidence intervals include zero in the additive case and 1 in the multiplicative). If we surveyed enough women, it is possible that we would be able to detect some statistically significant interactions. The statistical significance depends in part on the sample size. If you don't have too many Bhutanese students in your data, it will be hard to detect even the main effect, much less the foreign friends interaction. On the other hand, if the effect is huge, you might be able to detect it with only a few students. Perhaps you can try grouping students by continent instead of country, though too much data-driven variable transformation is to be avoided.

Generally, OLS and non-linear models will give you similar results. If they don't, as may be the case with your data, I think you should report both and let you audience pick. [Some people](http://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/2012/07/probit-better-than-lpm/) believe OLS/LPM is more robust to departures from assumptions (like heteroscedasticity), [others disagree](http://davegiles.blogspot.com/search?q=LPM) vehemently. You can and should justify a preferred model in various ways, but that's a whole question in itself. Personally, I would report both clustered OLS and *non-clustered* logit marginal effects (unless there's little difference between the clustered and non-clustered versions). You can also use an LM test to rule out heteroscedasticity.

Finally, with dummy-dummy interactions, I believe the sign and the significance of the index function interaction corresponds to the sign and the significance of the marginal effects. For continuous-continuous interactions (and perhaps continuous-dummy as well), that is generally not the case in non-linear models like the logit.

Answer (score 0):

The standard error indicates the uncertainty of the coefficients. One simple way to get a feeling for the uncertainty is to extract random subset of your data and compare the coefficients for each.

A major cause of such uncertainty is descriptors that are correlated. Two highly correlated descriptors can make a significant joint contribution to the outcome, but their relative contributions are undetermined. (The OLS calculation behind the scenes is trying to invert a nearly degenerate matrix.

In your case, country of origin and having foreign friends are probably correlated - you would need a lot of data to find stable coefficients for their relative contributions.